# How to store FileList object inside Vue data

Tags: javascript, file, vue.js

Hello im trying to store a FileList object inside vue data object but it's being stored as string "File"

Im adding a ref to html like this

```
<input type="file" @change="fileChange($event.target)">
```

And in the javascript

```
new Vue({
   el: '#someEl',
   data: {
      file: null
   },
   methods: {
      fileChange (file) {
        this.file = file.files[0]
      }
   }
})
```

As a result i get this:
[image: Result]

[image]

Comment: `this.file=e.target.files[0]`  &  `@change="fileChange($event)"` should work

Comment: Don't know vue, nor this console output, but are you sure this is a string? That would be a really strange string output (`[object File]` would be more expected here). Also, notpicking, but it is a File objevt you are trying to store here. The FileList is the object above.

Comment: @Helpinghand that didn't work either :( it is still stored as [object File]

Comment: @Kaiido yes It's stored as [object File] when I double click it. the console Its because It's the vue developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just pass argument `$event` to `fileChange()` instead of `$event.target`.
Now you can access file object using `evt.target.files[0];` inside `fileChange()` function.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      file: {}
   },
   methods: {
      fileChange (evt) {
        this.file = evt.target.files[0];
        console.log('file Object:==>',this.file);
      }
   }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="app">    

  
  <p>
   <input type="file" @change="fileChange($event)">
   name: <b>{{file.name}}</b>
  </p>
  <p>
    size: <b>{{file.size}} </b> 
    & type: <b>{{file.type}}</b>
  </p>
</div>
```